# is used destructuring in Promise.resolve with value thenable Object?

Tags: javascript, promise, destructuring

The following code use `Destructuring`:

```
var obj = {
  fun1:function() { console.log('Working') }
};

obj = { fun1:function(){ console.log("Replaced Working")} }

obj.fun1();

//output:
//Replaced Working
```

**Does the following `Promise` do the same?**

```
var pr = Promise.resolve({then:function(resolve){
  resolve(20);
  }
})


pr.then(function(v){
  console.log(v);
})
```

that's mean,`pr` is equal `Promise` object that,its `then` method changed to:

```
function(resolve){
  resolve(20);
}
```

and finally,`pr.then(function(v){...}` produces result.if don't use of `Destructuring` ,so why there is passed `then` property in `Promise.resolve`?

Comment: Could you change your question title?  It really isn't clear what it means.  I don't understand "Has been used destructuring".

Comment: There is no destructuring here

Comment: You're just passing a thenable object literal to `Promise.resolve()` this is a documented use case. It's difficult to know what you are asking.

Comment: No, it does not do the same obviously: your first snippet logs `Replaced Working`, while your second snippet (asynchronously) logs `20`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The following code use Destructuring

No it does not. Destructuring would be

```
 const { fun1 } = obj;
 fun1();
```

You are just rewriting a property.

> Does the following Promise do the same?

No it does not. `resolve` is an internal function of the promise constructor that then calls all the functions passed into `then`s. There is no property rewritten at all.

> why there is passed then property in Promise.resolve?

I don't know, that makes no sense at all. If you do:

```
 const pr = Promise.resolve(42);
 pr.then(console.log) // 42
```

If you pass an object in, it will resolve to that object:

```
 const pr = Promise.resolve({ some: "thing" });
 pr.then(console.log); // { some: thing }
```

If that object has a `then` method it is called a `thenable` object and the promise will follow that function assuming is has a signature of `function(onFulfill, onReject)`. This is what your last example it doing.

Comment: Why not wait for clarification on the question or simply vote to close?

Comment: @zero298 to prevent others from answering. And i voted to close already.

Comment: This doesn't prevent anyone from answering.  Voting to close prevents people from answering.

Comment: @zero298 not really. It takes way to long until 5 votes are casted. And I'm also trying to help the OP which is way easier in an answer with formatting etc.

Comment: @JonasW. if it has a `then`property that points to a function it *does* matter.

Comment: @mark right, feel free to edit / answer or should I?

Comment: @JonasW. ,Thank you!!!

Comment: @nehsan no worries, this was a community achievement :)